# Finding the random distribution with missing pieces

Tags: probability, random-variables

Im having a bit of trouble with solving a problem in probability, in which im given that:
X~U(1,3)
Y|X=x ~U(1,x)

and i need to find the random distribution of the variable Y. First i thought i can just assume that Y has Uniform distribution as well, but i cant prove it so i cant really assume that.
Any tips or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: "random distribution" is not the correct terminology here. Just call it "probability distritution" of "distribution". Btw, it is completely determined by its cumulative distribution function (CDF).

Comment: thanks, im studying a basic probability course so im pretty new to this :)

Comment: are these continuous or discrete variables?

Comment: they are discrete

Comment: If they are discrete (I don't think so) then for which $c\in\mathbb R$ do we have $P(X=c)>0$ and/or $P(Y=c)>0$? One of the characteristics of discrete random variables is that such constants exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's look at it case by case in terms of $Y$.

First, $P(Y=1)$:

- There is a $1/3$ chance that $X=1$. 
  When this is the case, $Y \sim U(1, 1)$ so  $P(Y=1 \mid X=1) = 1$.
- There is also  $1/3$ chance that $X=2$. In that case $P(Y=1 \mid X=2) = 1/2$
- Finally, $P(X=3) = 1/3$ and $P(Y=1 \mid X =3) = 1/3$

To now find $P(Y=1)$, we sum up the cases:
$$
P(Y=1) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{11}{18}
$$
As you can see, the general formula is
$$
P(Y = y) = P(X =1)P(Y = y \mid X = 1) + P(X =2)P(Y = y \mid X = 2) + P(X =3)P(Y = y \mid X = 3)
$$
Then $P(Y =2)$ and $P(Y =3)$ can be calculated similarly.

Note that you should end up with $P(Y =1) + P(Y=2) + P(Y=3) =1$

Comment: thanks, one last question- does this mean that they are independent? if not then i cant really find E[XY] because E[XY] !=E[X]*E[Y] right?

Comment: @dvd280 Well, they are definitely **not** independent. For example, $P(Y=1, X=1) = P(Y=1 \mid X=1)P(X=1) = 1/3$, whereas $P(Y=1)P(X=1) = \frac{11}{18} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = 11/54$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$P(Y\leq y)=\int P(Y\leq y\mid X=x)f_X(x)dx$$
where $f_X$ denotes the PDF of $X$.

**Hint2** (leaving out integrals)

Make a picture and try to grasp that $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is uniformly distributed on the triangle bordered by the lines $y=1$, $x=3$ and $y=x$.

Comment: Hey, we still havent seen the use of integrals in our probability course so i cant really unedrstand this unfortunately.